# Como fazer o calculo de cada voto de um total em porcentagem?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gente eu to com dificuldade em um programa em que pede o numero da camisa de cada jogador e a pessoa digitando o valor da camisa ela vai ta votando em uma camisa de jogador e essa camisa só pode ir até o numero 25 ai eu fiz um vetor com 25, 0 e quando a pessoa digitar o valor da camisa ela vai somar 1 na posição da camisa. Fiz uma também pra saber quem recebeu mais votos, mas eu n sei pq as vezes ela buga e da outro valor que n era pra ser o maior, e eu preciso fazer uma função que calcula a porcentagem de votos que cada um recebeu só que eu n to conseguindo fazer essa parte, eu até montei a função que calcula mas como que eu vou colocar pra aparecer a porcentagem de cada voto ?.
To tentando fazer essa bagaça tem um século e n consigo, por favor alguém me ilumine sou apenas um iniciante na programação que sofre em prog 1 na facul :(

```
def calc(vetor,votos):
  a = (votos/len(vetor))*100

def Votos(vetor,votos):
  continuar=True
def Votos(vetor,votos):
  while continuar==True:
    i=int(input("Número do jogador (0=fim): "))
    if i==0:
            continuar=False
    else:
        if i>25 or i<0:
            i= int(input("Informe um valor entre 1 e 25 ou 0 para sair!"))
        
        vetor.append(i)
        votos[i-1]+=1
def calcMaior():
maior=0
for t, ind in enumerate(vetorVoto):
    if ind>maior:
        maior=t+1
return maior
```

##### PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL

```
vetor=[]
porcentagem=[]
vetorVoto=[0]*25
maior= Votos(vetor,vetorVoto)
print(vetor)
maiorr= calcMaior()



print("o maior é %d"%maiorr)
print("com %d votos"%vetorVoto[maiorr-1])
print(vetorVoto)
```

Answer (score -3):

Segue a solução para o problema se não entender alguma parte é só perguntar:

```
import os


votos = [0] * 25
numero_de_votos = 0

while True:
    resposta = int(input('Número do jogador (digite 0 para sair): '))
    # Limpa o terminal
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    if resposta == 0:
        # Sai do loop se a resposta for 0
        break
    elif resposta < 0 or resposta > 25:
        print('Digite um número entre 0 e 25: ')
        # Retorna para a linha condicional do loop que é While True:
        continue
    # Soma o voto ao jogador e aumenta o numero de votos
    votos[resposta - 1] += 1
    numero_de_votos += 1


def calcula_porcentagem(votos):
    porcentagem = votos * 100 / numero_de_votos
    # Formata como porcentagem, substitui pontos por virgulas
    # o :.2f depois de porcentagem significa formatar com 2 casas
    # decimais depois da virgula, ou seja, o numero que for 16.6666666
    # fica 16.66
    return f'{porcentagem:.2f}%'.replace('.', ',')


for i, v in enumerate(votos):
    # enumerate retorna um tupla com o valor da lista e seu indice, então 
    # nesse caso i é o indice e v é o número de votos para aquele jogador
    print(f'Jogador {i + 1} teve {v} votos: {calcula_porcentagem(v)}')


# Imprime quem recebeu mais votos, max retorna o maior valor da lista
# votos.index(max(votos)) retorna o indice do maior valor da lista
print(
    f'\nQuem recebeu mais votos foi o jogador ' +
    f'{votos.index(max(votos)) + 1} com {max(votos)} votos'
)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: consegui fazer de um outro jeito tbm vou coloca no comentario abaixo caso alguem precise de ajuda nisso tbm

Answer (score -3):

Depois de muitas tentativas consegui fazer assim

```
def calcEImpressao(vetor,votos):
maior=0
for idd, e in enumerate(votos):
    if e>0:
        a = (votos[idd]/len(vetor))*100
        print("O camisa %d teve %d votos com %d porcento dos votos" %(idd+1,e,a))
        if e>maior:
            camisa=idd
            maior=e
            p=a
print("")
print("foram computados %d votos"%len(vetor))
print("")
print("melhor é o %d teve %d votos com %d porcento dos votos" %(camisa+1,maior,p))
  

def main(vetor,votos):
continuar=True

while continuar==True:
    i=int(input("Número do jogador (0=fim): "))
    if i==0:
            continuar=False
    else:
        if i>25 or i<0:
            i= int(input("Informe um valor entre 1 e 25 ou 0 para sair!"))
        
        vetor.append(i)
        votos[i-1]+=1
print("")    
calcEImpressao(vetor,votos)
```

##### PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL

```
vetor=[]
porcentagem=[]
vetorVoto=[0]*25
calculo= main(vetor,vetorVoto)
print("")
print("os votos: ")
print(vetor)
```